# TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

I cant get past this error, please help!
Heres the error:

```
  line 107, in <module>
        Player.update()
    TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

heres the full code:

```
     
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
 
pygame.init()
 
screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 1000
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Platformer by doody')
 
tile_size = 50
 
sunimg = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ale48\Desktop\python\platformer\assets\sun.png")
bgimg = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ale48\Desktop\python\platformer\assets\sky.png")
 
def draw_grid():
    for line in range(0, 20):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, line * tile_size), (screen_width, line * tile_size))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (line * tile_size, 0), (line * tile_size, screen_height))
 
 
class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        img = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ale48\Desktop\python\platformer\assets\guy1.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(img, (40, 80))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
 
    def update(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
 
 
 
 
class World():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.tile_list = []
        dirt_img = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ale48\Desktop\python\platformer\assets\dirt.png")
        grass_img = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\ale48\Desktop\python\platformer\assets\grass.png")
 
 
 
        row_count = 0
        for row in data:
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    photo = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    photo_rect = photo.get_rect()
                    photo_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    photo_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (photo, photo_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
 
                if tile == 2:
                    photo = pygame.transform.scale(grass_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    photo_rect = photo.get_rect()
                    photo_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    photo_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (photo, photo_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1
 
    def draw(self):
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])
 
 
world_data = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]
 
player = Player(100, screen_height - 130)
world = World(world_data)
 
run = True
while run == True:
 
    screen.blit(bgimg, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(sunimg, (100, 100))
 
 
    draw_grid()
    world.draw()
    Player.update()
 
 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
 
    pygame.display.update()
 
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You meant `player.update` instead of `Player.update`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a method of the `Player` class where I guess you actually want to call `update()` on the `Player` instance `player`. Try `player.update()` (with lowercase).